# Salvar resultados de uma query em um array

Tags: sql, array, microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

boa tarde!

Preciso pegar os resultados dessa query:

```
sql = "SELECT controle.ID FROM controle WHERE BP = '" & controlectform.nmbpbox.Value & "';"
```

E salvar em um array. Posteriormente eu farei um for each nesse array e irei usar os resultados armazenados em uma nova query.

O For Each eu já fiz mas os dados não são inseridos no meu array, então a consulta só roda a primeira vez.

Segue abaixo o código completo.

```
Function InsereDados()

    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim vContador As Integer
    Dim cn  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim arrid() As String
    Dim toid As Variant


    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & enderecoDB & ";Jet OLEDB:Database"

    cn.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    sql = "SELECT controle.ID FROM controle WHERE BP = '" & controlectform.nmbpbox.Value & "';"

    rs.Open sql, cn

    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount

    arrid(0) = rs(0)

    Next

    For Each ID In arrid

    Call SelectIDENT
    Call SelectBENEFIT
    Call SelectBP
    Call SelectCPF
    Call SelectNome
    Call SelectADM
    Call SelectFilial
    Call SelectSOLICITANTE
    Call SelectDTSOLIC
    Call SelectRECEBIMENTO
    Call SelectENVIO
    Call SelectRETIROU
    Call SelectMINUTA
    Call SelectCARTAO

    vArray = Array("", SelectIDENT, SelectBENEFIT, SelectBP, SelectCPF, SelectNome, SelectADM, SelectFilial, SelectSOLICITANTE, _
        SelectDTSOLIC, SelectRECEBIMENTO, SelectENVIO, SelectRETIROU, SelectMINUTA, SelectCARTAO)

    count = 2

        With Worksheets("Planilha1")
           For vContador = 1 To UBound(vArray)
           .Cells(count, vContador).Value = vArray(vContador)
            Next vContador
        End With
    count = count + 1

   Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está em usar a propriedade recordcount como verificação para seu [FOR]. O recordcount só vai possuir informação após você percorrer o recordset. Como solução eu sugiro:

opção 1:
Antes de fazer o [FOR] 
.
.
.
    rs.movelast
    rs.movefirst
.
.
.

Opção 2:
Use a propriedade EOF (End of file). Esta propriedade possui valor false até que chegue ao final do recordset, ou seja, a última linha.

Outro ponto é que como você vai preencher seu array e você não sabe a quantidade de registros retornados, você deve redimensionar o tamanho do seu array, neste caso você deverá usar o comando REDIM.